# What's the clojure way to builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, builder

We usually use builder pattern in java, like this:

```
UserBuilder userBuilder = new UserBuilder();
User John = userBuiler.setName("John")
                      .setPassword("1234")
                      .isVip(true)
                      .visableByPublic(false)
                      .build();
```

Some of the attributes have default value, and some haven't.

Passing attributes in a map may be a solution, but it makes the argument really longer:

```
(def john (make-user {:name "John" :pass "1234" :vip true :visible false}))
```

So, my question is, is there a elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: The builder pattern is in my opinion really just a work around for a lack of named parameters. Initializing a set of fields distinguished only as positional arguments is extremely cumbersome and very hard to read later, hence the builder pattern. Map destructuring achieves the same goals in a single function call, as Ankur suggests split a map onto multiple lines to maintain readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to construct some clojure structure, you can use destructuring pattern in function arguments. You will then achieve the similar thing you have already wrote.

```
(defn make-user [& {:keys [name pass vip visible]}]
  ; Here name, pass, vip and visible are regular variables
  ; Do what you want with them
)

(def user (make-user :name "Name" :pass "Pass" :vip false :visible true))
```

I doubt that you can do something in less code than this.

If you want to construct Java object (using its setters), you can use the approach Nicolas suggested.

Comment: For completeness, answering about your default values, destructuring support defaults values with `or`: `(defn make-user [& {:keys [name pass vip visible] :or {vip true}}]`

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. I would also add that if the variable default value is not set in `:or` map and it is not specified in the actual call, it becomes `nil`.

Comment: How do you imagine the thrush (`->`) would work in place of `doto`, since the return value of those method calls is not `this`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Somehow I hadn't remember that when I was writing, and also I (obviously mistakingly) thought that I saw somewhere about these macros interchangeability. Removed this notice.

Answer (score 4):

I would normally pass attributes in via a map - there's no real issue with doing this since the attribute map is really just one argument to the make-user function. You can also do nice stuff inside make-user like merge in default attributes.

If you really want to construct such a map with a builder pattern, you can do it with a threading macro as follows:

```
(def john 
  (-> {}
    (assoc :name "John")
    (assoc :pass "1234")
    (assoc :vip true)
    (assoc :visible false)
    make-user))
```

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite

`(def john (make-user {:name "John" :pass "1234" :vip true :visible false}))`

into multiple lines:

```
(def john (make-user {:name "John" 
                      :pass "1234" 
                      :vip true 
                      :visible false}))
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use the [doto](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-%28doto%20instance-expr%20%28instanceMethodName-symbol%20args%2a%29%2a%29) macro:

Here is an example to populate an array list with some values:

```
(def al (doto (java.util.ArrayList.) (.add 11) (.add 3)(.add 7)))
```

Stuart has [some perfect examples](http://stuartsierra.com/2010/01/03/doto-swing-with-clojure) on how to use doto with Swing.
Here with a Panel:

```
(doto (JPanel.)
            (.setOpaque true)
            (.add label)
            (.add button))
```

Here with a Frame:

```
(doto (JFrame. "Counter App")
  (.setContentPane panel)
  (.setSize 300 100)
  (.setVisible true))
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, no one mentioned [defrecord](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord) which gives you *"builder functions"* automatically

```
(defrecord User [name pass vip visible])

(User. "John" "1234" true false)
;;=>#user.User{:name "John", :pass "1234", :vip true, :visible false}

(->User "John" "1234" true false)
;;=>#user.User{:name "John", :pass "1234", :vip true, :visible false}

(map->User {:name "John" :pass "1234" :vip true :visible false})
;;=>#user.User{:name "John", :pass "1234", :vip true, :visible false}
```